# Bootstrap datepicker doesn't send value to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm doing a form in which i have a Date Picker.
The value is shown on an `<input>` but the problem is, when i submit the form, i don't get any value from the Date Picker on the Data Base.

I've run some tests, and if i replace the date picker with a simple `<input type="text">` the value is sent to the db, which makes me think that the problem is HTML related and not with the PHP.

Here is my HTML form code:

```
<form action="insert/insertReport.php" id="newReport" method="post">    
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="reportDate">Data</label>
     <br>
     <div class="bfh-datepicker">
         <div class="input-prepend bfh-datepicker-toggle" data-toggle="bfh-datepicker">
         <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
         <input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="form-control">
         </div>
         <div class="bfh-datepicker-calendar">
             <table class="calendar table table-bordered">
                 <thead>
                    <tr class="months-header">
                       <th class="month" colspan="4">
                          <a class="previous" href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                          <span></span>
                          <a class="next" href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                       </th>
                       <th class="year" colspan="3">
                           <a class="previous" href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                           <span></span>
                           <a class="next" href="#"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                       </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="days-header"></tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                 </table>
              </div>
         </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

And this is the insertReport.php

```
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['date']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO reports (date) VALUES ('$date')";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    mysqli_close($link);
    header('Location: ../reports.php');
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Error adding report.";
}
```

I'm using the Date Picker from the bootstrap form helpers.
Here is the link: http://js.nicdn.de/bootstrap/formhelpers/docs/index.html

Comment: What if you replace `$_REQUEST['date]` by `$_POST['date']` ?

Comment: what is the data type of date in reports table ?

Comment: @executable doesn't work aswell.

Comment: check the date format. Issues is with date format you send datePicker to MySQL

Comment: @ArsalanAkhtar varchar(10)

Comment: @AbdullaNilam if i send the date with same date format, written in an <input> text, the mysql gets it.

Comment: print your query before execution and paste here 
INSERT INTO reports (date) VALUES ('$date')

Comment: @MiglAraújo add datePicker JS code

Comment: try printing `$_REQUEST['date']` and show us the output.

Comment: @VamsiKrishnai'm having issues connecting to the ftp now, will print ASAP.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna i'm getting 0.

Comment: the problem must be in the HTML, because it is not collecting the date picker info to store on the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the JavaScript, since it was giving me an undefined value for the tag name of the `<input>`.

I changed it to `name="date"` and its working fine now.

Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with your date format. Normally DATE type in MySQL will accept only 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. I think your bootstrap date is gibing a different format. So try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO reports (date) VALUES ('".date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date))."')";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i added your code line, and now its adding the date, but it is adding a default date instead of the date i select in the date picker. It adds: 1970-01-01

Comment: What value are you getting in $_REQUEST['date'] ?

Comment: I'm getting 0 , no value.

Comment: Array ( [username] => test [client] => test [local] => test [report] => test )

I'm doing print_r($_REQUEST); and i get values for all other strings, except for the date. It is not collecting any info from the date picker.